# How to restrict json schema to not support a particular data type

Tags: java, json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator, customvalidator

I want to restrict my application to only support "string" type values for json configuration.
Json schema by default supports a set of datatypes such as integer, boolean, etc however, the parsing logic in my application only supports string values.

How do I make sure the schema does not define a property of any type except string.

Allow  - { "key1": "A", "key2": "B" }

Reject - { "key1": "A", "key2": true} or { "key1": "A", "key2": ["1","2"]}

Comment: Can you say more about the structure of the JSON? e.g. is it just a one-dimensional object of key/value properties, or more deeply nested? Should arrays be allowed in the structure?

Comment: it is one dimensional sructure. no arrays allowed. eg
{ "key1": "A",  "key2": "B"} 

Example to not allow - { "key1": "A",  "key2": true}

Answer (score 0):

This would be the most basic example to match your requirements. Each `property` defines a `type` (data type). This `type` keyword is the constraint applied to that property

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
    "description": "a basic schema",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "key1": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "key2": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    }
}
```

Take a look at this [fundamentals post](https://json-schema.org/blog/posts/applicability-json-schema-fundamentals-part-1) from the JSON Schema blog for a nice introduction to understanding JSON Schema.

Comment: Hi Jeremy. As mentioned, I would like the schema itself to be restricted, so that no on defines a schema with any type other than string. So that i can run the json config against the schema and validate it. I am looking for solution in terms of  extending json validator to not allow a particular type.

Comment: in that case, you can write a metaschema for the schema to be defined and restrict it to `type: string`